# BufferedImage not showing transparency when subimaged from a spritesheet

Tags: java, graphics

Solved the problem: No matter how many times I kept deleting the pixels and setting it to transparent on my photo editor, I switched to paint.NET and it worked! :)

http://prntscr.com/5bontg

That is my spritesheet, it is transparent. I've loaded it in with my SpriteSheet class:

package com.pokemoniridium.Framework;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

```
public class SpriteSheet {
    public BufferedImage spriteSheet;

    public SpriteSheet(BufferedImage spriteSheet){
        this.spriteSheet = spriteSheet;
    }

    public BufferedImage grabSprite(int x, int y, int width, int height){
        BufferedImage sprite = spriteSheet.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
        return sprite;
    }
}
```

To load it in:

```
SpriteSheet spriteSheet = SpriteSheet(loader.loadImage("/assets/Gold_Walking.png"));
```

Then I load it in an array, like so:

```
sprites[0] = this.spriteSheet.grabSprite(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

Then I render it:

```
g.drawImage(sprites[0], x, y, null);
```

By the way, the loader variable is an instance of my BufferedImageLoader class:
http://pastebin.com/SB0P8aav

The problem still persists, strange. Any ideas guys?

When I grab an image using that method, it returns the image but without the transparency. I've used both PNG and GIF?

Is there anyway I can grab an image and get the transparency with the image?

Comment: You've zoomed in on the subimaging being the culprit, but I'd rather suspect it is either the way you load the initial spritesheet or how you draw stuff. A subimage does not contain "new" data, it maps directly to the pixels of the source buffer.

Comment: SpriteSheet spriteSheet = SpriteSheet(loader.loadImage("/assets/Gold_Walking.png"));

Then I load it in an array, like so:

sprites[0] = this.spriteSheet.grabSprite(0, 0, 50, 50); //first img

And then I render it:
g.drawImage(sprites[0], x, y, null);

The problem still persists, strange. Any ideas guys?

Comment: ... so what is this 'loader' variable? And add code to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, I've appended it to my question. It's just simply an instance of a class which loads and returns the image.